# How can I use custom domain with call back function in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want my flutter app to use the custom domain not the firebase domain when calling the firebase function, and I want to use the callback not the http way, is that possible?
I want to call it this way:
final result = await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('FunctionName').call();

I already connected the custom domain to my firebase project, but now it is not using it, it is just using the firebase domain.

Comment: Why do you need a _custom domain_ if you are using `onCall()` functions? I don't think you have to specify the URL anywhere as long as you are using Firebase SDK. Are you referring to Firebase hosting domain?

Comment: Some of my users can not access my app because for some reason Firebase is blocked for them, it works when they use my custom domain that's how I fixed almost every thing in the app, except the call back function.